# Bridge non-adjacent monitors in three monitor setup

Tags: macos, display

I would like to use the following 3 monitor setup because the arrangement aligns logically with the physical placement of the monitors.

[image: Displays: Arrangement]

Is it possible to bridge the gap between the left and right monitors, above the primary?

**OR**

Is it possible to detect and move the mouse via scripting?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. I remembered a utility to wrap around the mouse. For example from the right edge of the right display to the left edge of the left display. I searched for this  utility to see if it would work for your case, but could not find it. This was a long time ago, and it might have been a Classic Mac OS utility.

Comment: @LeeJoramo Hmmm. Maybe if there was way to detect when the mouse is at a certain part of monitor 2, and then jump the mouse to monitor 3.

Comment: There are utilities that detect the mouse at the screen edge. For example: [Teleport](http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/) allows your mouse and keyboard to jump to the screens of OTHER computers.

Comment: Still an open question. @LeeJoramo Teleport seems nice, but its for multiple computers, not monitors. I'll checkout [slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate). It's a bit complex, but feature-packed.

Comment: Another option might be [cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/)

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking outside the box a minute…

…wouldn't *this* achieve something close to what you want, without the need for any external solution.

It would give you a clean 'jump' between the external screens, balanced against a slight loss of accuracy in the transition between the top left & your main screen.

[image]

Comment: Yes and no. Appreciate the suggestion. Sure, this solves the problem of moving between monitors. But the disparity between the physical location vs the virtual location was enough to dissuade me from doing this.

Comment: Appreciate that, no worries. I just found your question whilst 'mooching' around old questions rather than looking for something specific, & thought 'ooh, maybe if?' [I also just found a typo in my answer…]

Comment: Hey @Tetsujin, at least you're honest ;)