# Allow mouse to cross displays that are not touching in Arrangement

Tags: display, mouse

I have the following display arrangement:
[image]

The reason there is a gap between the top 2 displays is so that my mouse cursor lines up correctly (or as close as possible) when going from the top<->bottom displays. Unfortunately, with this gap, this does not allow me to move the cursor between the top 2 displays. If I move the displays so they are touching, then it works fine, but my mouse cursor is then off when moving vertically.

Is there a way to keep the displays spaced, but allow the cursor to cross between?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it can't be done unless you match the edges in that control panel - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150502/bridge-non-adjacent-monitors-in-three-monitor-setup/219496#219496 & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-warp-the-border-between-two-different-sized-monitors-so-the-mouse-doe/219502#219502 for a couple of different situations, with the same result

Comment: Actually, after further testing, I have found that if I move the pointer quickly, it has no problem switching displays.

Answer (score 0):

This is a paid feature of the [Cursr](https://cursr.app/) app, available for macOS and Windows.

It's a little janky in some ways, but it definitely solves this particular problem well, which as far as I can tell, literally nothing else does:

[image: screenshot of the main Cursr window on macOS, showing a display-layout that involves teleporting across gaps]

To set it up,

1. upgrade to Cursr Pro;
2. create a border-teleport that jumps from one display to another (like the orange one in my above screenshot);
3. hover your mouse near the top of the display-edge until the cursor turns into arrows;
4. click and drag the top of the teleport-zone away from the display-edge until it matches your setup appropriately.